# What will be the derived set of the set, $S = \{\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2})| n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

As per me the set $S = \{-1, 0, 1\}$.
So the derived set, $D(S) = \emptyset$.

Is the answer correct, because at one place it's mentioned $D(S) = \{-1, 0, 1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $S=\{-1,0,1\}$ (assuming that when you wrote $I$ you meant $\mathbb N$) and therefore $S'=\emptyset$.

Comment: $I$ is the set of Integers.

Comment: @AjayChoudhary The standard symbol is $\mathbb Z$ then.

Comment: By $S'$ you mean Derived Set, right?

Comment: @AjayChoudhary Yes. That's the standard notation.